# YouTube iframe for Windows 8 app

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, windows-store-apps, winjs

So I'm using YouTube's iframes in order to show some videos in my app. The thing is I cannot make the videos fullscreen.

I'm using this code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RnYcPJTtV1A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you write that on a single html file the browser (all of them) will show you the `fullscreen` button on the far right. But, that same code on a Win8 app (html of course) will display the video but will not show the fullscreen button.

Do you thing that's what YouTube (google) wants? I mean, should I be doing anything different?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried the YouTube Player API instead of using the standard iframe embed?

Comment: yes I have, but for what I've seen YouTube does not provide a way to reach the video file... I know there are 'alternate' ways, but I rather stay on the good side :)

Comment: Can you please file a bug using the instructions in this blog post: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html and supply as much information as you can? I am not sure full screen is supported for HTML5 video embed in Win8 HTML apps but we'll follow up internally and with Microsoft if required. Pls comment with a bug link once submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Sebastian,

Something to keep in mind is that iframe within a Windows Store app is designed for limited use only. The [certification requirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx) 2.4 states:

> The primary experiences your app provides must take place within the
>   app

One needs to be very careful about including content from sites you do not control via iframe in a Windows Store app, because this content can change without warning in ways that may break your app or introduce unexpected behavior.

Because YouTube videos may use either Flash or HTML5 for playback, you may find that some videos simply will not play in the context of a Windows Store app, because ActiveX controls are not available in that context.

Given all that, I would not expect to be able to play full-screen video embedding YouTube videos via iframe in a Windows Store app.